# Quartz piezoelectric battery

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, batteries, piezoelectric

I'm designing a battery that uses quartz crystals to hold/produce a current for a long time using piezoelectricity.

My question is:
Would it be more efficient to have multiple small quartz crystals and have them all under pressure and connected in parallel or to have one large crystal and place that under stress to produce electricity?

-edit- By efficiency I mean which would output more electricity, is it a surface area thing or just volume? Based on what I've researched I would guess volume is more important based on the fact that it is each molecule that causes the current, but I don't know if surface area would affect it.

I'm not sure if this is a feasible idea or not, my knowledge of piezoelectricity is rather limited however if you make the assumption that the crystal + force = electricity then surely this would work?

Comment: I think that you need to flesh out your ideas a bit more because from your question it sounds like you're a bit fuzzy about what you're trying to accomplish. What do you mean by asking about which is the "more efficient" option? Do you mean more efficient in terms of electrical power delivery to the battery? That's probably not a concern for your purposes. Or are you asking for more efficient in terms of minimizing the amount of quartz needed? Or more efficient in terms of minimizing the fabrication effort including wiring everything together? Or more efficient in terms of the total cost?

Comment: @SamuelWeir Thank you for pointing that out. I meant efficiency in terms of cost of manufacturing the crystal(s) (to make them the right shape etc) to electrical output ratio. Basically which would put out more electricity, I can figure out the cost part. Will edit question to reflect this,